# NodeJS - HTTPS POST request not working with Got client

Tags: node.js, https

I am trying to make a HTTPS Post request using the Got client. The endpoint requires TLS with a client certificate. This is what my request looks like:

```
await got.post('https://example.com/some-entity/', {
                json: requestPayload,
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'some token'
                },
                https: {
                    certificate: fs.readFileSync('sslfile.cert.pem'),
                    key: fs.readFileSync('sslfile.key.pem'),
                    passphrase: 'passphrase',
                    rejectUnauthorized: false // only for local dev. would be true in prod
                },
                responseType: 'json'
            });
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
write EPROTO 139745222879040:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40\n
```

I am following [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#advanced-https-api) Got documentation.

I have confirmed the certs and keys are good because the same request works from postman and curl. It even works if I use a different Javascript client like `Request`.

Anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. I was using an older version of Got(9.6.0). It worked fine after I upgraded my Got version to 11.8.0.